# I keep getting this error Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, web, react-dom

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import  firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import ThreadDisplay from './ThreadDisplay/components/ThreadDisplay';

class google extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const config =
     {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: "",
      measurementId: ""
    };
     this.app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    
    this.database = this.app.database();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ThreadDisplay database={this.database} />
    );
  }
}
export default google;
```

I am initializing firebase app only one Time then I am getting this error again and again.
Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). so how do I solve this

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only place you call `initializeApp`, it might be that the component is created multiple times.

If you can't find a spot that is guaranteed to be called only once, I usually find it easiest to explicitly check if we're initialized Firebase before with:

```
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    
    this.database = this.app.database();
}
```