# Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). Nextjs + firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Im using nextjs + firebase and im trying to run the auth and db but as i found out the app runs twice with cuz of nextjs..
Here's my firebase.js file

```
import firebase from "firebase";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

  const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "................I",
  authDomain: ".......firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "htt.......firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "......",
  storageBucket: "......appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "....",
  appId: "...........",
  measurementId: "G-......",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

I tried many solutions with adding snippets but nothing works as im still new to firebase

Comment: Try the trick I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343480

Comment: I saw this snippet as solution so many times but i dont even know where to commit it

Comment: You'd put the `if` around your current `const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` line, as that is what raises the error. If that doesn't solve the problem, edit your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let app;
try {
  app = firebase.initializeApp({...});
} catch (e) {
  app = http://firebase.app();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid data fetching troubles i used this technique, it works just fine.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14420#discussioncomment-29816